# remove duplicate files

Tags: find, osx, regular-expression

On my Mac OS X 10.6.7, iTunes duplicated every single file in my music library. Now I have 3,840 files instead of 1,920. The problem is that iTunes didn't simply duplicate the whole folder, but each file in each folder, adding a `1` to the duplicate. It looks like this:

```
├── album1
│   ├── track1.mp3
│   ├── track1 1.mp3
│   ├── track2.mp3
│   └── track2 1.mp3
└── album2
    ├── track1.m4a
    └── track1 1.m4a
```

Now rather than clicking on 1,920 duplicates, I want to enter some smart line in the Terminal to get rid of the extra files:

`find path/to/music/ -name "* 1.*" -delete`

Though this will work in most cases, it will mess up things in the following situation:

```
└── album2
    ├── track 1.mp3
    └── track 1 1.mp3
```

Maybe I should exclude `"* 1 1.*"` and later on rename those files removing the extra `1`?

**How do I do this?**

**Is there a simple solution to this?**

Comment: Please specify the environment. Is this OS X?

Comment: You are right — see edit! I am asking this on UNIX & LINUX because I think it's more likely you guys know...

Comment: Nothing wrong with asking here about using the OS X terminal, as OS X is a Unix system. It just helps if you specify the environment because otherwise people are likely to assume that you are on Linux, with a GNU userland. (The mention of iTunes jarred with this, which prompted my request for clarification.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this, haven't tested; it's in bash so you may have to convert some syntax:

```
IFS=$'\n'              # so that only newlines separate words, not spaces
set -f                 # disable globbing
FILES=$(find path/to/music/ -name "* 1.*")

for FILE in ${FILES}; do
    if [[ -f "${FILE% 1.*}" ]] ; do
        echo "Matched ${FILE}."
        # rm "${FILE}" # Uncomment me once you have confirmed it would do what you intend.
    fi
done
```

`${FILE% 1.*}` strips the last match of the `1.*` syntax from the end, `[[ -f ... ]]` checks whether that file would exist; therefore, it would remove the files for which the file without the syntax at the end would exist. Please test before uncommenting `rm`, to be sure it is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually I simply tested if there would be a conflict with `find . -name "* 1 1.*" -print`. This listed 5 files, which I manually renamed after cleaning the folder with: `find . -name "* 1.*" \! \( -name "* 1 1.*" \) -delete`

Answer (score 5):

I'd also add that to successfully find (and remove) *exact* file duplicates, you have to compare files by hash:

```
#!/bin/sh -eu
find "${1:-.}" -type f ! -empty -print0 | xargs -0 md5 -r | \
    awk '$1 in a{sub("^.{33}","");printf "%s\0",$0}a[$1]+=1{}' | \
    xargs -0 rm -v --
```

Save this as `deldupes.sh` and run it giving dirname as 1st parameter (otherwise `$PWD` would be used).

Tested on OS X, works for long whitespaced filenames.